# Translation of "She is a genius"

Tags: traduction, pronoms

> She is a genius.

How to say this in French? If "genius" were a profession, we would say

> Elle est génie.

But since "genius" is not a profession, I think we need an article. But I'm not sure whether we should say

> Elle est un génie.

or

> C'est un génie.

Also, how can we translate the same sentence but with the pronouns "I" or "you"?

> I am a genius.
>
> You are a genius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since *genie* is a noun and it is not a profession we need an article.So,we should say **C'est un genie**,also because we can't use an indefinite article after *il est /elle est*.

Comment: Thank you. How can we translate "I am a genius" or "You are a genius" then? I don't think we can still say "C'est un génie"?

Comment: "C'est" is used to present another person instead of il/elle est,so I think we can say "Tu es un genie" or "Je suis un genie".

Comment: I don't think *"elle est un génie"* would be wrong. It's maybe more literary. Still, *"c'est"* is used in 99 % of cases, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Pour répondre à la deuxième moitié de la question, quand on dit

> X est un génie.

ou

> C'est un génie.

on veut plutôt dire que quelqu'un est très intelligent. Mais quand on dit

> Tu es un génie.

on fait généralement référence à un fait précis, plus qu'à l'intelligence de la personne en général. Plutôt synonyme de

> Ton idée est géniale.

(Ou bien il s'agit de sarcasme, signifiant "Tu te prends pour un génie.")